# Is GeoServer Image Pyramid upscaling?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, resampling, image-pyramids

I have an *Image Pyramid* in *GeoServer 2.2 RC3* (not the latests - I know, but I have other pyramids working here).

The total size is around 1TB and file size is around 1-2GB for each GeoTIFF.

When looking at the results using WMS, it all looks blurred. Going into the GeoServer log, I found that when I request an image, it selects the level which I think is causing it to upscale the result to fit the screen:

Request: 
Size in pixels: 1632x960
Size in meters: 1406x827

I have a *GSD = 1 meter/pixel* at the level GeoServer selects (which is 3). Shouldn't it select level 2 with a *GSD = 0.5 meter/pixel* to ensure GeoServer downsamples the result - thus loosing information instead of creating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default GeoServer picks the closest resolution to the one you're asking for. Programmatically one can set three different policies, but I don't believe the setting is exposed anywhere in the GeoServer GUI.
You may want to open an improvement request at [jira.codehaus.org](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS).

Comment: **@Andrea**: You write that the GUI doesn't expose the setting, but can I edit some configuration file or similar to select a different policy?